# Fortran confusion, modules, declarations, dummy arguments

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran, numerical-integration

my problem is to integrate a function using romberg integration. I am retaking this class and was successful last semester but this time around my professor is requiring modules, which I could never figure out. Another problem has always been dummy arguments. The basic layout is this

```
Global variable module >
Main prog >
external fn within prog >                       
subprogram romberg (module, uses function)
```

I placed my "x" variable in the global variable module but am not sure where I need interfacing and where I need the USE statement. I can't get the romberg module to compile because it's not seeing the x variable I declared no matter where I place it.

```
MODULE globvar
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER,PARAMETER:: dp=selected_real_kind(15)
REAL(dp)::a,b,epsil,cp,h,x,mu
REAL(dp),PARAMETER::pi=3.141592653589, m=45000.0, D=1.032, Ts=250.0, k=0.153
INTEGER::maxit,nt,n,exitflag
END MODULE globvar
```

Romberg Mod

```
MODULE romod
CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE Romberg(f,a,b,nt,epsi,maxit,exitflag,n)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp = selected_real_kind(15)
REAL(dp),INTENT(IN)::a,b
INTEGER,INTENT(IN)::epsi,maxit
INTEGER,INTENT(OUT)::exitflag
INTEGER,INTENT(INOUT)::nt
REAL(dp),DIMENSION(maxit+1,maxit+1)::T
REAL(dp)::sone,stwo,h
INTEGER::r,n,I,j,k

INTERFACE !Interface function ! I was told this wasnt needed then it was
FUNCTION f(x)
USE globvar
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER::f
END FUNCTION f
END INTERFACE

Romberg algorithm omitted, unless asked for. x is being passed to an upper and lower limit
END SUBROUTINE Romberg

END MODULE romod
```

Main Prog

```
PROGRAM Waste
USE globvar
USE romod
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, EXTERNAL::f

INTERFACE
FUNCTION f(x)
USE globvar !Use Module Variables
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER::f
END FUNCTION f
END INTERFACE

read prompts

CALL Romberg(f,a,b,nt,epsi,maxit,exitflag,n)

END PROGRAM Waste

FUNCTION f(x)
USE globvar !Use Module Variables
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER::f

f=x**3

END FUNCTION f

END PROGRAM Waste
```

Any help would be appreciated. This is my 5th semester using fortran and some of the rules still elude me.

Comment: To request help with a university assignment and end with 'I'm not fond of spending a day debugging' might not get you many replies. Perhaps you should rephrase to focus specifically on one issue, like 'where I need interfacing ' Maybe this has already been answered http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fortran+interfacing

Comment: Thank you, I'll continue to search. To be fair, this is my 5th semester in a 3 part class series as an engineering major and fortran has been my crux. Eventually it just takes up too much time when there are other classes to focus on that are just as intense.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for the function `f` to be external? You can certainly do it this way (and you're close), but it's cleaner and interface-free if you don't.

Comment: I think your immediate problem is that you're trying to define `x` twice - once as a global variable and also as an input to the function `f`. Should they be the same thing?

Comment: Only reason it's external is that the professor is asking for it to be external, otherwise I'd wrap it in the main program to simplify things. The only thing he mentioned as dummy arguments were the function name, using fun1 for the main program and external function, and f in the subprogram. This same logic was used last semester, but only gave me errors. When I made it "f" all around it compiled.

I took x out of the global module and made an INTENT(IN)::x in the function and it compiled just fine! Thank you. Now my problem is that my a.out / a.exe file won't run locally or on school servers

Comment: @Jake  What do you mean "won't run" - can you edit the question to include the new error message? Also, consider adding an `@Ross` when responding to my question - I may see it faster that way.

Comment: Sorry @ross I'm getting used to this website as a resource. I appreciate the help a lot. My a.out command wouldn't work but I found I had to use ./a.out which was never the case. On my local machine I was getting stuck in the do loop in my romberg algorithm but when I connected to my university servers the program ran but is giving me trouble, there's a lot to account for. I'm assuming this is because of syntax errors and spent a while checking calculations. I may post a more specific topic. I can't seem to output my romberg answer to a variable in the main prog.

Comment: @ross There is a constant (var/pi*var) in front of my integral but the whole function is being integrated which may be the problem. Either way I appreciate you taking time out of your day to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of stuff going on here, but just addressing the dummy variable issue think about this,

suppose I have a 'global' variable `x` via `use module` both in calling program and a function and I do this:

```
 USE globvar
  ...
 x=2
 y=3
 z=f(y)
```

..

```
 function f(x)
 USE globvar
 f=x^2
```

!! is x 2 or 3 ??
Of course this is logically inconsistent, and will fail to compile. (and no the compiler will not be satisfied if you painstakingly only ever call `f(x)` )

My advice is to avoid the use of global variables all together.

re: interface, there is nothing about your function that requires an explicit interface in the first place.